Not able get email threads for CC and BCC addresses using Microsoft graph api: forward api
I am using microsoft graph api's foward api to fowrad mail with CC and BCC, as I can't add CC and BCC address directly when we use fowrad api, I have created MIME format and added it over headers.
Now I am receiving two mails one for To address(with email thread) and another for To, Cc, and Bcc address (without email thread, but with last mesage).
Expected: mail triggering for To, CC and BCC addresses with email thread.
This is the function, where I construct MIME
def construct_mime_message(self, recipient, email_body, subject, cc_recipients=[], bcc_recipients=[], attachments=[]):
        print(f"Constructing mime message: {recipient}, {cc_recipients}, {bcc_recipients}")

        message = MIMEMultipart()
        message["To"] = recipient

        if cc_recipients:
            cc_header = ", ".join(cc_recipients)
            message["Cc"] = cc_header

        if bcc_recipients:
            message.add_header("Bcc", ", ".join(bcc_recipients))
        message["Subject"] = subject

        html_part = MIMEText(email_body, "html")
        message.attach(html_part)

        if attachments:
            for attachment in attachments:
                try:
                    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
                    part.set_payload(base64.b64decode(attachment["contentBytes"]))
                    encoders.encode_base64(part)
                    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', f'attachment; filename="{attachment["name"]}"')
                    message.attach(part)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error attaching file {attachment['name']}: {e}")

        message_as_str = message.as_string()
        return base64.b64encode(message_as_str.encode("utf-8")).decode()`

Below is the function to foward mail using fowrad api
def foward_email(self, target_email, external_id, access_token, email_body, subject, to_address, cc_addresses=None, bcc_addresses=None):
        try:
            messages_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{target_email}/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=conversationId eq '{external_id}'"
            headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}
            messages_response = requests.get(messages_url, headers=headers).json()
            message = messages_response["value"][0]
            latest_email_id = message["id"]

            mime_message = self.construct_mime_message(to_address, email_body, subject, cc_addresses, bcc_addresses)
 
            forward_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{target_email}/messages/{latest_email_id}/forward"

            headers = {
                "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
                "Content-Type": "text/plain",
                'Prefer': 'outlook.timezone="India Standard Time"'
            }

            fwd_response = requests.post(forward_url, headers=headers, data=mime_message)

            if fwd_response.status_code == 202:
                print("Mail sent successfully")
                return True
            else:
                logging.error(f"Failed to send update email. Status code: {reply_response.status_code}")
                logging.error(f"Response content: {reply_response.content}")
                return False

        except Exception as ex:
            logging.error(f"An error occurred: {ex}")
            return False

Result: > Mail triggred for CC and BCC without emial thread.
> Receiving mail twice, one is for To address and other is for T0, Cc and BCC addresses
-Your response will be appreciated

Sounds like a bug eg when your message is parsed server side (Exchange will convert it back from Mime to TNEF to be sent) it's being parsed incorrectly. Because its all happening server side (in the cloud) your best option would be to log a support ticket with Microsoft so they can have a look. Otherwise you can post a the mime content your trying to send so someone can maybe spot an issue that can be fixed client side before the send or possibly reproduce the same issue.
